# I'm making my portfolio, and I'd like to use the Spotify API to show what I'm currently listening to, but don't want to use the Play button

Tags: javascript, css, html, spotify

Mostly self-explanatory, but I just want the song title and artist sent as a JavaScript plain text object, so I can style it myself in CSS. And possibly a way for it to link back to the song on Spotify would be cool too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Link your spotify to Last FM - http://www.spotify.com/uk/about/spotify-on-the-web/spotify-last-fm/

Then grab an API Key when you've signed up for Last FM and you can show what you've listened too with the following script (requires jQuery) & html:

```
<ul>
<li class=”artist”>Artist: &nbsp; </li>
<li class=”track”>Track: &nbsp; </li>
</ul>  


$.getJSON('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=[USERNAME]&api_key=[KEY]&format=json', function(data) {

var artist = $(".artist"),
track = $(".track"),
artistVal = data.recenttracks.track[0].artist["#text"],
trackVal = data.recenttracks.track[0].name;

artist.append(artistVal);
track.append(trackVal);

});
```

Replace **[Key]** with API key and **[Username]** with your Last FM username

Answer (score 1):

We don't have an API to do that directly, but there's a couple of approaches:

1) If you're on Mac OS, write a little application to use Spotify's AppleScript dictionary to see what's playing and upload it somewhere.

2) If not, write a Spotify App that runs inside Spotify and uploads the info. However, you'd have to keep that app active or it'll be suspended.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to configure the Spotify client to [scrobble](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Scrobble) to facebook and then use the [open graph api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) to query it.
You'll need to get an access token for yourself requesting the music.listens permission, then access it via: https://graph.facebook.com/me/music.listens

Comment: Same would go for last.fm, I believe they too have an API which you could use to do the same (if you don't like FB for some reason).